# Makefile doesn't recompile when linker script changes

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a `Makefile` as follows. `make` doesn't recompile the program when the linker script `riscv32i.ld` changes. What do I need to do to add a dependency on that file?

```
AS=riscv32-unknown-elf-as
CC=riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc
OC=riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy
CFLAGS=-nostdlib -T riscv32i.ld
MAKEFLAGS += --silent
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.asm)

OBJ=$(patsubst %.asm,%.o, $(SOURCES))
ELF=$(patsubst %.asm,%.elf, $(SOURCES))
HEX=$(patsubst %.asm,%.hex, $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(HEX)

$(HEX): %.hex: %.elf
    $(OC) -O binary $< $@

$(ELF): %.elf: %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ): %.o: %.asm
    $(AS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.elf *.hex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm an idiot. Just adding `riscv32i.ld` as a prerequisite to `$(ELF)` works:

```
AS=riscv32-unknown-elf-as
CC=riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc
OC=riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy
CFLAGS=-nostdlib -T riscv32i.ld
MAKEFLAGS += --silent
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.asm)

OBJ=$(patsubst %.asm,%.o, $(SOURCES))
ELF=$(patsubst %.asm,%.elf, $(SOURCES))
HEX=$(patsubst %.asm,%.hex, $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(HEX)

$(HEX): %.hex: %.elf
    $(OC) -O binary $< $@

$(ELF): %.elf: %.o riscv32i.ld
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ): %.o: %.asm
    $(AS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.elf *.hex
```